# Percona Server keeps throwing errors on Ubuntu, but i cant remove it

Tags: apt

I attempted to install percona's tools on ubuntu and had issues. I abandoned the idea of using it.

Now upon removal it keeps kicking this error:

> The following packages will be REMOVED:
>
> percona-release
>
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 162 not upgraded.
>
> After this operation, 48.1 kB disk space will be freed.
>
> Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
>
> (Reading database ... 54695 files and directories currently installed.)
>
> Removing percona-release (0.1-3.trusty) ...
>   N: Ignoring file 'percona-release_0.1-3.trusty_all.deb' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
>   N: Ignoring file 'percona-release_0.1-3.trusty_all.deb' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

Can I just delete those files without messing anything else up, then remove the rest of the package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me it looks like your issues come from a file with a suffix not being .list. Could you share the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`?

Or have you placed `percona-release_0.1-3.trusty_all.deb` into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`? If so please remove it.

Comment: files in folder: ondrej-php-trusty.list ; ondrej-php-trusty.list.save;  percona-release_0.1-3.trusty_all.deb;

Your fix worked, had to remove .deb :)